# Prop mismatch server/client, how to generate a unique ID that persists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm using ReactJS.net with server rendering. I want to make a simple component that outputs a label and an input where the label references the input via the htmlFor property. Since this component could be used multiple times on the same page I need it to have a unique ID for every instance of the component.

Thus I generate a guid in the constructor and use that - which works fine except that the ID gets generated both on the server side and then on the client side which leads to a mismatch of values.

How can I solve this mismatch?

Example code:

```
interface IProps { whatever:string }

export default class Test extends React.Component<IProps> {
    private _guid: string;

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this._guid = Utils.getGuid(); // generates a new guid
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor={this._guid}A nice label</label>
                <input id={this._guid} type="text" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Code will run and work but will generate a warning:

Warning: Prop `htmlFor` did not match. Server: "87d61dbe-b2a8-47bd-b299- 
c6e80445f626" Client: "f0297b42-7781-48a4-9904-75b8fd2d1140"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution:

Create a ref for the label and input elements. In the componentDidMount() lifecycle function assign "id" and "htmlFor" to these elements with a generated value.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._labelRef.htmlFor = this._guid;
    this._inputRef.id = this._guid;
}
```

Now this._guid will still be two different values from server to client, but React won't warn about it since I'm applying the values after Mount.

Comment: Probably thats not the best idea to update DOM after mount of universal component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build an ID basing on the props passed to the component - in this case, you can create hashcode using `whatever` string.

Comment: Passing an ID as a prop will result in the same behaviour as long as the ID gets generated from within a react component (parent component in this case). The only way I've managed to solve it is to pass an ID as a prop from the Razor view that initially kicks off rendering the component. Maybe that was what you meant? I would like to solve this from within javascript if possible!

Comment: @MathiasMothander What I ment is you should not use random IDs when dealing with SSR. If your component takes properties like `title="My component"` / `title="My second component"` - this is enough to make them unique - use `title` (in your case `whatever`) property as a key or generate a hashcode out of them.

Comment: Gotcha, however this component will not really take anything unique as a prop, that's why I tried to generate a random ID for it. I suppose I could introduce something that would be unique to it - but then that would only be for the purpose of this ID problem, nothing else.